# Override collectTotals in Magento2

Tags: magento2

How to override collectTotals function inside

> Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalManagement

Using plugin in `Magento 2`?

Comment: Which class, collectTotals method you want to pluginize?

Comment: Class cartTotalManagement needs to be pluginized

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of plugins before, after and around.
You can use any of it as per your use.
I have just demonstrated about "before".

> Create di.xml at  app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
        <plugin name="CustomQuote" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Quote" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Create: app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Quote.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Quote
{
    public function beforeCollectTotals() {
        die('your custom code');
    }
}
```

Thanks